# How to count elements in an array in c

Tags: c, arrays, count, element

In C, how can I count how many times a specific element appears in an array ? And then how to display that count to the user ?

For example, if I have an array consisting of `{1, 2, 2, 2, 3}`. How can I write a code that tells me `2` appears 3 times, then display this to the user?

Comment: http://rapidpurple.com/blog/tutorials/c-tutorials/programming-in-c-arrays-and-loops/

Comment: You should try posting some code or pseudo-code or thoughts or anything about your attempt. My suggestion is to write how you would do it yourself (if you were a machine) on paper. Then see if you could translate that to code. You'll certainly reach hiccups in the translation, but then you have much smaller and more specific questions to think about.

Comment: Are there any constraints on the range of values that can occur in the array? If it is only positive values less than 1000, say, then this is trivial - just have a second array for the counts. If any possible value can occur, then it is not so simple.

Comment: This didn't answer my question I know how to print the the elements in an array using a loop what I'm stuck on how to do is how to actually count how many times a specific element appears

Comment: @user2151446 how can I do this using a second array?

Comment: So,what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to count all elements: Assuming array can only contain a limited range of integers, declare another array of length the maximum entry in the first array. Iterate through the first array and increment the location in the second array index by the first array, then print out the second array.

Pseudocode:

```
 int nums[] =  {1,2,2,2,3};

 int counts[10];  // assume entries in nums are in range 0..9

 for(i = 0; i < length of nums; ++i)
 {
     num = nums[i]; 
     if(num < 0 or num >= length of counts)
        handle this somehow
     ++counts[num];
 }
 for(i = 0; i < length of counts; ++i)
 {
    printf("%d occurs %d times\n", i, counts[i]);
 }
```

If you only want to count a particular value:

```
int count_in_array(int value, int* array, int length)
{
    int count = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        if(array[i] == value)
            ++count;
    }
    return count;
}

...
int nums[] =  {1,2,2,2,3};
printf("%d occurs %d times\n", 2, count_in_array(2, nums, 5));
```

Comment: Or lose the `if` with `count += array[i] == value;`